# Getting internet on Win XP guest with Win 7 Home Premium Host using VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

My Windows XP guest cannot browse the Internet. My host is Win 7 home premium.

What are the possible causes for this?

Comment: How did you configure the networking?

Answer (score 1):

Your networking on the Virtual Machine needs to be set to Bridged mode. To do this you must power down the guest OS and change the network adapters settings to Bridged.

This link has more details on Bridged Networking:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#id471083

Answer (score 0):

Configure the network settings to either use NAT or Bridged networking. NAT gives the machine a completely new address and works as a router. Bridged is when the host and guest connect to the network using separate IP addresses. Use either/or. Both should work in connecting you to the internet.

Comment: -1 for wrong: "Bridged is when the host and guest share the same IP address"

Comment: Instead of downvoting, why did you not edit my post to fix it?